# Why does the compiler generate a right-shift by 31 bits when dividing by 2?

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86, disassembly, sar

I have disassembled code produced by the compiler, and I see that it has produced the following sequence of instructions:

```
mov     eax, edx
shr     eax, 1Fh
add     eax, edx
sar     eax, 1
```

What is the purpose of this code?

---

I know that

```
sar     eax, 1
```

divides by 2, but what does

```
shr     eax, 1Fh
```

do? Does this mean that `EAX` will be either 0 or 1 if the left bit was either 0 or 1?

This looks strange to me! Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 10):

The quick answer to your question—what is `shr eax, 1Fh`—is that it serves to isolate the uppermost bit of `eax`. It might be easier to understand if you convert the hexadecimal `1Fh` to decimal `31`. Now, you see that you're shifting `eax` right by 31. Since `eax` is a 32-bit value, shifting its bits right by 31 will isolate the very top bit, such that `eax` will contain either 0 or 1, depending on what the original value was of bit 31 (assuming that we start numbering bits with 0).

This is a common trick for isolating the *sign bit*. When a value is interpreted as a signed integer on a two's-complement machine, the uppermost bit is the sign bit. It is set (== 1) if the value is negative, or clear (== 0) otherwise. Of course, if the value is interpreted as an unsigned integer, the uppermost bit is just another bit used for storing its value, so the uppermost bit has an arbitrary value.

---

Going line by line through the disassembly, here's what the code does:

> ```
> mov     eax, edx
> ```

Evidently, the input was in `EDX`. This instruction copies the value from `EDX` into `EAX`. This allows subsequent code to manipulate the value in `EAX` without losing the original (in `EDX`).

> ```
> shr     eax, 1Fh
> ```

Shift `EAX` right by 31 places, thus isolating the uppermost bit. Assuming that the input value is a signed integer, this will be the sign bit. `EAX` will now contain 1 if the original value was negative, or 0 otherwise.

> ```
> add     eax, edx
> ```

Add the original value (`EDX`) to our temporary value in `EAX`. If the original value was negative, this will add 1 to it. Otherwise, it will add 0.

> ```
> sar     eax, 1
> ```

Shift `EAX` right by 1 place. The difference here is that this is an *arithmetic* right shift, whereas `SHR` is a *logical* right shift. A logical shift fills the newly-exposed bits with 0s. An arithmetic shift copies the uppermost bit (the sign bit) to the newly-exposed bit.

---

Putting it all together, **this is a standard idiom for dividing a signed integer value by 2 to ensure that negative values are correctly rounded**.

When you divide an *unsigned* value by 2, a simple bit-shift is all that is required. Thus:

```
unsigned Foo(unsigned value)
{
    return (value / 2);
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
shr  eax, 1
```

But when dividing a signed value, you must deal with the sign bit. You could use `sar eax, 1` to implement a signed integer division by 2, but this will cause the resulting value to be rounded toward negative infinity. Note that that is different than the behavior of the `DIV`/`IDIV` instruction, which always rounds towards zero. If you want to emulate the round-towards-zero behavior, you need some special handling, which is precisely what the code you have does. In fact, GCC, Clang, MSVC, and probably every other compiler will all generate precisely this code when you compile the following function:

```
int Foo(int value)
{
    return (value / 2);
}
```

This is a *very* old trick. Michael Abrash discussed it in his *Zen of Assembly Language*, published *circa* 1990. ([Here is the relevant section](http://www.jagregory.com/abrash-zen-of-asm/#signed-division-with-sar) in an online copy of his book.) It was surely common knowledge among assembly-language gurus long before that.